# Как правильно составить цикл Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, функции

Здравствуйте. Передо мной стоит задача сделать список рубрик, под рубриками выводятся все записи в количестве 9 штук, если больше, то нужна цифровая пагинация. При нажатии на ссылку рубрики происходит сортировка записей через и меняется соответственно пагинация для уже нового списка. Изначально была реализована Ajax сортировка, но в дальнейшем при добавлении пагинации, она не учитывает уже отсортированные записи, и не удается почему то таким образом вывести изначально на страницу только 9 записей, выводятся сразу все. Может кто подсказать как можно сделать, желательно с примером. А то пока wordpress на низком уровне.

blog.php

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url() ?>/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php" method="POST" id="filter">
    <section class="portfolio-banner">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Блог компании</h2>
            <span>Думаем и размышляем</span>
            <ul class="p-list">
                <?php
                if( $terms = get_terms( 'category', 'orderby=name' ) ) :
                    foreach ($terms as $term) :
                        echo '<li data-termid="'. $term->term_id .'">' . $term->name . '</li>';
                    endforeach;
                endif;
                ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="may blog">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="projects" id="response">

                <?php
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

                $args = array('posts_per_page' => 9,
                              'paged' => $paged);
                $custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : 
                   $custom_query->the_post();   
               ?>
               <div class="project">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><div class="project-img" style="background: url('<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>')"></div></a>
                    <p class="may-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                    <p class="may-annotice"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <p class="post-date"><?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?></p>
                </div>
              <?php endwhile; ?>

            </div>
            <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {
                pagination($custom_query->max_num_pages);
            } ?>
        </div>
    </section>
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="myfilter">
```

functions.php

```
    function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
         echo "</div>\n";
     }
}
function true_filter_function(){
    // для таксономий
    if(!empty($_POST['foliocat'])) :
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'folio_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['foliocat']
        );
    endif;

    if(!empty($_POST['postcat'])) :
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $_POST['postcat']
        );
    endif;

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );


    if(!empty($_POST['foliocat'])) {
        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                echo '<div class="project"><a href="'.get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()).'"><div class="project-img" style="background:url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')"></div></a>';
                echo '<span>'. get_the_title() .'</span>';
                echo '<p>'. get_the_excerpt() .'</p>';
                echo '<p class="post-date">'. get_the_date('d/m/Y') .'</p></div>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'No posts found';
        endif;
    }


    if(!empty($_POST['postcat'])) {
        if( $query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();
                echo '<div class="project"><a href="'.get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()).'"><div class="project-img" style="background:url('.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().')"></div></a>';
                echo '<span>'. get_the_title() .'</span>';
                echo '<p>'. get_the_excerpt() .'</p>';
                echo '<p class="post-date">'. get_the_date('d/m/Y') .'</p></div>';
            endwhile;
            wp_reset_postdata();
        else :
            echo 'No posts found';
        endif;
    }


    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_myfilter', 'true_filter_function');
```

main.js

```
    $('#filter .p-list li').click(function(){
    var that = this;
    var filter = $("#filter");
    var datas = {
        action: 'myfilter'
    };
    if($('section').is('.may.blog')){
        datas['postcat'] = jQuery(that).data("termid");
    }else{
        datas['foliocat'] = jQuery(that).data("termid");
    }
    console.log(datas);
    $.ajax({
        url:filter.attr('action'),
        data: datas, // данные
        type:filter.attr('method'), // тип запроса
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            filter.find('#response').text('Загружаю...'); // изменяем текст кнопки
          },
          success:function(data){
            $('#response').attr("data-curcat", jQuery(that).data("termid"));
            $('#response').html(data);
          }
        });
});
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: > Может кто подсказать как можно сделать, желательно с примером. А то пока wordpress на низком уровне.

Можно и нужно воспользоваться давно изобретёнными велосипедами. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: @SeVlad а будет ли пагинация через плагин учитывать сортировку записей?

Comment: Если сортировка делается правильно, то будет. Что мешает поставить плагин и посмотреть?

Comment: @SeVlad если бы все было так просто скачать плагин и все)) Придется к нему читать документацию, вставлять код какой то куда то)) пока все получится) Посмотрю, может конечно и поставлю, спасибо)